# Why is HierarchicalArray2D used in openslam_gmapping?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

openslam_gmapping uses HierarchicalArrary2D to store the map. HierarchicalArray2D is something like a 2D array, and each cell of it is a 2D array again.

So if a map's size is 256 * 256, size of HierarchicalArray2D is 8 * 8, and each cell of it is a 32 * 32 2D array.

I'm a bit confused about the data structure above, why don't we use an Array2D directly? Does HierarchicalArray2D has any advantages?

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223926/why-is-hierarchicalarray2d-used-in-openslam_gmapping?/) by [chenkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25551/chenkan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm no gmapping developer, but there are two advantages to the approach that immediately come to mind:

- When resizing (especially extending) the map, already existing submaps do not have to be touched. For a continuous map, this would be different and generally requires a complete map rewrite.
- Spatially neighboring cells are close to each other in memory. This can be advantageous due to fewer cache misses when accessing the map.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chenkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25551/chenkan/) on 2016-01-19**:
Brilliant!